# Compute posterior expected loss for choosing B over A

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, inference

The bayesAB package in r computes the posterior expected loss for choosing B over A when running the following commands:

```
library(bayesAB)
test <- bayesTest(treatment, control, distribution = "bernoulli", priors = c("alpha" = 1, "beta" = 1))
summary(test)
```

This is the r code behind this function which can be found [here](https://github.com/FrankPortman/bayesAB/blob/master/R/util.R):

```
  # Expected loss from switching from B to A
  getPostError <- function(A_samples, B_samples, f = function(a, b) (a- 
  b)/b) {
  BoverA <- B_samples > A_samples
  loss <- f(B_samples, A_samples)
  coalesce(mean(BoverA) * mean(loss[BoverA]))}
```

- Shouldn't the Bayesian expected loss be computed by multiplying the posterior probability of each variant with an assigned risk as mentioned in [this](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/bayesian/minimizing-expected-loss-for-hypothesis-testing-lQ6HW) video?
- Can someone explain the logic behind using the last line `coalesce(mean(BoverA) * mean(loss[BoverA]))`? Is this the squared loss?